# Les paso mi código que estoy utilizando en mi HTML y BOOTSTRAP pero no me funciona, no me doy cuenta cual es el error que tengo

Tags: html, bootstrap

Este es el código que utilizo desde bootstrap, seguí las instrucciones que dice en la página de bootstrap y no funciona, no se si estoy haciuendo bien las cosas o me estoy salteando algo, espero que alguien me ayude a para ver en que me he equivocado.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
   <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="images/turismo.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="turismo image">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="images/turismo2.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="Rturismo2 image">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="images/turismo3.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="turismo3 image">
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-bs-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-bs-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: *no funciona* es un error un poco vago, sabes? Qué es lo que no funciona? Mejor que añadir imágenes, añade un [mre]

Comment: Saludos. Que error te muestra o en dado caso el resultado erroneo y cual debe ser (lo esperado)? Si lo apoyas con imagenes igual ayuda cuando amplies tu planteamiento.

Comment: Les comento no me muestra ningún mensaje de error simple, cuando lo ejecuto queda con la primer imagen y no se cambia, por mas que presiones los botones previous o next, la imágenes con de 348x115 capas es porque son chicas, estoy usándolo con  chrome Versión 87.0.4280.88

Comment: Quizás te ayude abrir la consola del navegador con "F12" y ver si te muestra algún error al cargar la página o, chequear si están bien las rutas de los `.js`.

Comment: Veo que tienes un carousel. Si no funciona algo relacionado con javascript prueba a colocar todos los scripts por último dentro de la etiqueta body.

Answer (score 1):

He realizado una serie de cambios para probar y a mi me funciona.

- Lo primero que he hecho, es borrar tus enlaces externos de jquery y bootstrap, por los últimos y correctos desde un CDN
- Además de eliminar el de popper.js que ya está incluído en bootstrap.min.js
- A parte de eso, he cambiado los atributos que tenías data-bs-ride y data-bs-slide por data-ride y data-slide tal como se indica en la documentación de bootstrap y eso parece que resuelve el problema.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
      <div style="background-color: #666; border: 1px solid red; text-align: center;" id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide w-100" data-ride="carousel">
         <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/728x90.png?text=1" class="d-block w-100" alt="1">
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/728x90.png?text=2" class="d-block w-100" alt="2">
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/728x90.png?text=3" class="d-block w-100" alt="3">
          </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
        </a>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Qué rápido eres @BetaM !!!!!

Comment: Solo fue un poco de formato, espero no moleste

Comment: ¡Claro que no! es de agradecer ;)